# Webservice getting called multiple times

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am making 2 separate webservice calls asynchronusly, after 1st webservice response is received, I am making 2nd webservice call which leads to multiple threads being spawned of even though method is called once..

[image: App crashes- Multiple threads]

Comment: There is no multithreading going on here. The stacktrace very much says that you are recursing deeply inside the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not access property with "self" inside the setter for the property. Instead use backing store variable:

```
- (void) setLocationList: (NSArray *) brList
{
   _locationList = brList;
}
```

Accessing using self will call the same setter again and again recursively (until stack overflows and program halts).

Comment: however - (void) setSalesManList:  method works fine with self. Any reason why their it works but not with - (void) setLocationList: ? Note: both salesmanList and locationList are declared and synthesized same way..

Comment: Your property name is "salesmanList", and setter is "setSalesManList", note the "m" is lowercase in property and in uppercase in setter. So this is not the property setter, but your own method to set that property.